# Azure SQL: Keep alive option

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to enable and set the KeepAlive property on a Azure SQL database? I can't find it when i'm using Microsoft SQL Management Studio on the Azure database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry; that's not really an option. The keepalive option is really a TCP configuration setting that impacts the behavior of database connections; you do not have access to any machine/network configuration options in SQL Azure.

However SQL Azure already provides a built-in feature that automatically kills idle connections and long-running transactions; this should provide a similar outcome.

Comment: How long is the time interval before SQL Azure kills idle connections? The reason i needed the keepalive option is that the driver i'm using for MSSQL currently have a bug where it just looses the connection and it doesn't reestablish (and no the company who made the driver doesn't seem to fix the bug :-/). So if i could use the keepalive i could code a service that reestablish the connection at midnight.

Comment: The current timeout for idle connections is 30 minutes. See this link for more information about the general behavior of SQL Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx